# DropDownList chama a page load

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Tenho um *dropdownlist* que pega dados do banco *sql server*. Carrego esse *dropdownlist* na *page_load* dentro de um `if(!IsPostBack){}` e pelo que percebi do `!IsPostBack`, ele só entra ali se for a primeira vez que carrega a página.

O que me incomoda é que toda vez que clico em um dos itens do *dropdownlist*, a página recarrega. Colocando um ponto de interrupção no *page_load* da página, vi que vai ali toda vez que clico em um item.

Por que isso acontece?
Como fazer com que ele não recarregue a página para cada item escolhido?

Answer (score 1):

Só entrara no trecho de código `if(IsPostBack == false)` no momento que a pagina é carregada a primeira vez no servidor pois não foi executado um *Post* pelo cliente.

No seu caso quando você clicava em uma opção do *dropDownList*, automaticamente fazia uma requisição(um *Post*) ao servidor, com isso a pagina atualizava, porém não entrava na clausula `if(IsPostBack == false)` pois é um *PostBack*.

O `AutoPostBack = "true"` normalmente é utilizado para obter algum tipo de validação durante a seleção do item, o ideal é utilizar um updatepanel(apenas um trecho da pagina é atualizada através de uma chamada em ajax) para não ter a sensação que a pagina foi atualizada.

Se no seu caso, não há esse tipo de necessidade a melhor alternativa é deixar o `AutoPostBack = "false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei o que o fazia fazer isso, havia um AutoPostBack = "true" no dropDownList. Vou pesquisar a respeito, mas de forma simples, posso dizer que a página enviava dados ao servidor e depois retornava para o navegador por conta desse AutoPostBack.

Comment: utilize o AutoPostBack = "true" no dropDownList no form se vc precisa carregar um outro campo ou um outro dropDownList  que dependa do valor escolhido no primeiro, assim seu segundo campo será carregado.